# Convert data to colors like scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, color-mapping, matplotlib-animation

When using matplotlibs scatter function, it is pretty neat to display data with colors:

```
data = np.random.random((3, 10))
scatter = plt.scatter(data[0], data[1], c=data[2], cmap='Viridis')
```

This will automatically map `data[2]` to a color spectrum that conveys information. Is there a nice way to do that outside of the scatter function?
One reason why Im asking this is because I try to change the colors later. There is a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401658/how-to-animate-a-scatter-plot), but I realised that this will use the normalisation of the old array.

Say I want to change the array that is mapped as colors:

```
new_colors = 10 * np.random.random(10)
scatter.set_array(new_colors)
```

This will make almost all points the brightest color instead of choosing an appropriate new range of colors.
Is there a way to circumvent this? Or alternatively can I nicely make a colorarray from this and then pass it to `scatter.set_color()`

Comment: do you have a god reason why not just re scatter with new values? plt.scatter(data[0], data[1], c= new_colors, cmap='Viridis')

Comment: @YohaiMagan To create an animation, `set_array` is often helpful

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966121/updating-the-positions-and-colors-of-pyplot-scatter)

Comment: @YohaiMagan I assume this would take quite a bit longer than just uptdating the values

Comment: @JohanC So this is the nicest solution there is I guess?