# Arduino Live Serial Plotting with a MatplotlibAnimation gets slow

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino, pyserial, pyqtgraph

I am making a live plotter to show the analog changes from an Arduino Sensor. The Arduino prints a value to the serial with a Baudrate of 9600. The Python code looks as following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("com3", 9600)
ser.readline()

optimal_frequency = 100

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# the following arrays must be initialized outside the loop

xar = []
yar = []

print(time.ctime())

def animate(i):
    global b, xar, yar # otherwise a

    for i in range(optimal_frequency):

        a = str(ser.readline(), 'utf-8')
        try:
            b = float(a)
        except ValueError:
            ser.readline()
        xar.append(str(time.time()))
        yar.append(b)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar, yar)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=optimal_frequency)
plt.show()
```

A get an ok response time in the plot, but when I have been plotting over 20 minutes the reaction times increase to about 1 min. I.e. it takes 1 min forthe graph to get updated with the new values. I have also tried with PyQtGraph but that is delayed from a start.

Besides the delay for times over 20 minutes, I am getting some overshoots and undershoots in the plot.

Any help?

Comment: I think that the problem is that _xar_ and _yar_ variables get huge after some time. You may try using List comprehensions and perform a dynamic read of the list instead.

Comment: After 20 minutes you might as well stop plotting since your plot with more than 10 million connected dots will have become completely unreadable.

Comment: @Jalo thanks. I see the variables get too big. The problem is that I need to re-plot all of the values again, since I am clearing the plot everytime to not to overload its memory. I'll go down in sampling frequency :-)

Comment: What you are trying to do manages quite too data to dynamically plot all of the historic data at every iteration. For a simpler approach, I would store received data at every iteration in a file for further analysis and meanwhile plot only the last N iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, you are doing two things wrong:

- you keep appending incoming data to your arrays, which get huge after a while
- you clear your axes and create a new `ax.plot()` at every iteration.

what you want to do instead is:

in an initialization function, create an empty Line2D object

```
def init():
    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
    return line,
```

then in your update function (`animate()`), you use `line.set_data()` to update the coordinates of your points. However, to maintain performance, you have to keep the size of your arrays to a reasonable size, and so you will have to drop the older data as newer data comes in

```
def animate(i):
    (...)
    xar.append(str(time.time()))
    yar.append(b)
    line.set_data(xar, yar)
    return line,
```

Check out some tutorials [like this one](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/). There are also plenty of questions on SO that already answers your question. For instance, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23968127/1356000) contains all the elements you need to get your code working.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments refered to, reading from the arrays gets naturally slow due to their great size. With a baudrate of 9600 I get around 130 serial readings and time-stamps per second in the *xar* and *yar* variables; which after 20 min get a size of 156000. Reducing the baudrate to 2400 decreases the length of the variables to 36000, and that can be easily replotted.